# how to access json key and value in ajax

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, asynchronous

I want to access my json object with key as table header, and value with the same pattern that JSON Object has, and show in Html table.

```
history:{1/22/20: 2, 1/23/20: 3, 1/24/20: 5, 2/1/20: 19, 2/10/20: 32, 2/11/20: 33, 2/12/20: 33, 2/2/20: 19, 2/20/20: 35, 2/21/20: 35}
```

Code

```
for (var i = 0; i <= Object.keys(response.confirmed.locations).length; i++) {
                    var final = response.confirmed.locations[i].history;

                    $("#show").append("<tr>" +


                        "<td>" + final['1/22/20'] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + final['1/23/20'] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + final['1/24/20'] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + final['2/1/20'] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + final['2/10/20'] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + final['2/11/20'] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + final['2/12/20'] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + final['2/2/20'] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + final['2/20/20'] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + final['2/21/20'] + "</td>" +


                        +"<tr>")


                }
```

Comment: Change the line before last line ```+"<tr>"``` to ```+"</tr>"```

Comment: @SajeebAhamed plz explain which line.

Comment: Please share you full response for clearification.

Comment: This is an API that has data in JSON ( https://coronavirus-tracker-api.herokuapp.com/all ) and I want to show in the HTML table.

Answer (score 0):

`let yourJSON = ...`

Then you must parse yours json object using `JSON.parse(yourJSON )`

`let result = JSON.parse(yourJSON )`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

And then you can iterate the object using `Object.entries()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(result )) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

Comment: Shukriya! You made my day. Its Working! if I don't parse my JSON than also working.

Comment: how can I write your's suggested code inside the append function => table row?